# How can I get resource annotations in a Jersey 2.4 filter?

Tags: java, filter, annotations, jersey

My question is essentially the same as this one: [How can I get resource annotations in a Jersey ContainerResponseFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315188/how-can-i-get-resource-annotations-in-a-jersey-containerresponsefilter).

But I'm using Java Jersey 2.4 and can't find any sign of the ResourceFilterFactory or ResourceFilter classes. The documentation also doesn't mention them. Have they been deprecated or are they just really well hidden? If they've been deprecated, what can I use instead? Is there now a way with Jersey 2.4 and 2.5 to get the resource annotations from a ContainerRequestFilter?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to modify processing of a request based on annotations available on a resource method/class then I'd recommend using [DynamicFeature](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/DynamicFeature.html) from JAX-RS 2.0. Using `DynamicFeature`s you can assign specific providers for a subset of available resource methods. For example, consider I have a resource class like:

```
@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

And I'd like to assign a [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) to it. I'll create:

```
@Provider
public class MyDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceInfo resourceInfo, final FeatureContext context) {
        if ("HelloWorldResource".equals(resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getSimpleName())
                && "getHello".equals(resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getName())) {
            context.register(MyContainerRequestFilter.class);
        }
    }
}
```

And after [registration](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/) (if you're using package scanning then you don't need to register it in case it has `@Provider` annotation on it) `MyContainerRequestFilter` will be associated with your resource method.

On the other hand you can always inject [ResourceInfo](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) in your filter (it can't be annotated with `@PreMatching`) and obtain the annotations from it:

```
@Provider
public class MyContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getDeclaredAnnotations();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the second suggestion as it matches my requirement more closely, but I'm getting the following exception as soon as I add the ResourceInfo injection: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of mycompany.rest.framework.oauth2.AuthorizationRequestFilter errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on mycompany.rest.framework.oauth2.AuthorizationRequestFilter

Comment: Use Jersey 2.5.1 if possible or inject ResourceInfo using @Context javax.inject.Provider<ResourceInfo> in 2.4 (this has been fixed in 2.5).