# JAX-RS: map method entity based on method annotation

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am using JAX-RS 2.0 with Jersey 2.6. I was wondering if it was possible to have something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/get/{id}")
@MapTo(type = MyObjectDTO.class)
public MyObject getMyObject(@PathParam("id") String id){
  MyObject o = ...
  return o;
}
```

In the method above I am returning an instance of `MyObject`. However, I have defined the `MapTo` annotation to indicate that I want to map this object to `MyObjectDTO`. The way I was thinking this could work is to process the response early in a `ContainerResponseFilter`, detect the annotation `MapTo` and, assuming no error occurred, replace the entity in the response with an instance of `MyObjectDTO` created appropriately from the existing entity (of type `MyObject`).

However, I couldn't find a way to get the `Method` in the resource that was just called after the request came in, i.e., the `getMyObject` method, so that I can scan for the `MapTo` annotation.

Is there a way to achieve this in a JAX-RS-y kind of way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution by reading [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946815/how-can-i-get-resource-annotations-in-a-jersey-2-4-filter). I created a class that looks like this:

```
@Provider // or register in the configuration...
public class DTOMapperFeature implements DynamicFeature {
  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
    for (Annotation annotation : resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotations()) {
      if (annotation instanceof MapTo) {
        MapTo mapTo = (MapTo) annotation;
        // Note: additional validation (return type shouldn't be void, 
        // collections are out etc.) is required before creating this,
        // or should be pushed in the DTOMapperFilter.
        // You get the gist: this filter will map the entity to an instance
        // of the specified class (using a constructor in this case).
        context.register(new DTOMapperFilter(
          resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getReturnType(), 
          mapTo.getResponseType());
      }
    }
  }
  @Priority(/* appropriate priority here! */)
  public final static class DTOMapperFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    public DTOMapperFilter(Class<?> declaredReturnType, Class<?> responseType) { 
      // implementation omitted: find DTO constructor etc.
      // throw if responseType does NOT have a constructor that takes an instance
      // of declaredReturnType: catch errors at application bootstrap!
    }
    @Override
    public void filter(
      ContainerRequestContext requestContext, 
      ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        // implementation omitted: create instance of DTO class using constructor
      }
  }
}
```

Given sensible exceptions will be thrown from either the constructor of `DTOMapperFilter` or the `configure` method above, this should be pretty robust and errors detectable at test time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this some serious reason you cannot return dto object? Sounds very strange...You can probably use AOP but I guess it would be bad practive
Here the Spring AOP example
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/aop.html

Comment: n terms of developer API, we thought it might be nicer if the framework took care of object-to-DTO mapping since the DTO is really just a medium to transmit information to the client.

Comment: I think it will make your code hard to understand. Let's say MyObject is an entity object and since you don't want to pass the DB id of objects to client, you decide not to map id to your DTO. New developer probably will have hard time to find out why he sending some data in MyObject and don't get in on client side.

Comment: Any new developer will have to explicitly defined the DTO type in the annotation. That will be made clear and it's just a matter of diligence. I know this is not a very common JAX-RS practice but it's what has been decided.

Comment: And BTW we are not using Spring and not planning on using it. We were thinking about using Guice down the line for DI.